# how to implement the tournament data structure with flexibility for its application to any data type

Tags: c, data-structures

i am attaching my code that i have written so far. the prime problem in my code is the dereferencing the void pointer. i know its not possible in c but i am helpless to find the alternative.
the problem lies in the 2 functions setupTour and play. lets see the code first:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    typedef struct {
        int size;      /* number of players playing the Tournament*/ 
        void *largeVal; /* stores the tournament
        void *max;
        void *min;
        void *nextMax;
    } Tournament;

    /*Dynamically Allocates a space for new Tournament with each player having size "sizeofPlayer" bytes */
    Tournament *newTournament(size_t sizeofPlayer, int noOfPlayers) {
        Tournament *temp = (Tournament *) malloc(sizeof(Tournament));
        temp->size = noOfPlayers;
        temp->largeVal = (void *) malloc((2 * temp->size - 1) * sizeofPlayer);
        return temp;
    }
    /*fills the tournament leaf structure by copying the elements pointed by 'base', no of copies = tour->size. */
    Tournament *setupTour(Tournament *tour, void *base) {
        int i;
        for (i = tour->size; i < (2 * tour->size); i++) {
            *((tour->largeVal) + i - 1) = *(base++); // i am getting an error here 
                                                     // since void pointers cannot 
                                                     // be dereferenced.
        }
        return tour;
    }

    /*it is the implementation of the traditional tournament algorithm where a comparator is passed as a parameter for providing the natural ordering of the elements/players */
    Tournament *play(Tournament *tour, int (*comp)(const void *, const void *)) {
        int i;
        for (i = 2 * (tour->size) - 2;i > 1; i = i - 2) {
            void *j, *k;
            j = ((tour->largeVal) + i);
            k = ((tour->largeVal) + i - 1);
            if ((*comp)(j, k) == 1) {
                *((tour->largeVal) + ((i -1)/2)) = *j;
            }
            else {
                *((tour->largeVal) + ((i -1)/2)) = *k;
            }
        }
        return tour;
    }

    void printTour(Tournament tour, char *(*toString)(void *elem)) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 2 * tour.size - 1; i++) {
            printf("%s ", (*toString)(tour.largeVal + i));
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

`
```

can anyone help me to figure out how to circumvent this problem.

Comment: What are `largeVal` and `base` supposed to be (data-type wise) and why are you converting them to `void*`?

Comment: I am trying to implement this data structure to first find out the largest value thats why i named it so and yes i confess there are several other nit picks in my code which i need to figure out. This is the initial design. Currently i need to make it work first. Base is the pointer to the initial element or an address of an array holding the original players. Documentation is another nitpick, my fault!

Comment: You still haven't explained *what* the type of *"original players"* is (or why you are using a `void*`) - it's always easier to work with concrete types and I'm still unclear on why you need to erase it

Comment: I do not know the type of the original players that is the problem. I need a flexible code where my tournament can work for any data type thats why i called it flexible. Knowing the type is much easier to implement. For ex- Suppose if i have user defined data type student, complex no etc etc and user provides a comparator for natual ordering then everything can be done to that data type like sorting, max through this ds but i need to know how should user pass on type details so that i can make use of it. Just like the standard library function quick sort.  Do you get my point..

Comment: The [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) function of the standard library does not pass any type information to anything - it requires the size of each element of the array to be passed (as the third parameter) and internally it operates on `char*` types (you can check an implementation for details: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/qsort.c.html)

Comment: Okay i will see, i have to leave now. i will post in case if i have any confusion